# Partial method declaration in `.d.ts` not working

Tags: typescript

I'm using a for loop to add methods to a class with prototyping, something like this:

```js
for (let method of Object.keys(ElizaService.methods)) {
  // Map methods onto App class directly
  const { I, O } = ElizaService.methods[method]
  App.prototype[method] = async function (
    this,
    args: typeof I
  ): Promise<typeof O> {
    return await this.client[method]({
      appId: this.appId,
      key: this.key,
      ...args
    })
  }
}
```

TypeScript throws an error as expected. This is `index.ts`. I also add an `index.d.ts` file with the added methods (generated dynamically):

```js
export declare class App {
  createApp(): void
  createInstance(): void
  createItem(): void
  createRecipe(): void
  createTrade(): void
  readIdentity(): void
  readInventory(): void
  readItem(): void
  readInstance(): void
  readApp(): void
  readTrade(): void
  readRecipe(): void
  updateIdentityMetadata(): void
  updateInstance(): void
  updateItem(): void
  updateApp(): void
  updateTrade(): void
  updateRecipe(): void
  deleteApp(): void
  deleteInstance(): void
  closeTrade(): void
  verifyKey(): void
}
```

I included the reference in the former file with `/// <reference path="./index.d.ts" />`. But when I try to use the file in a different file, TypeScript throws an error:

[image]

Why doesn't this work? How can I resolve it?

(I've already restarted the TS server and also the window.)